# ADX: how can I recover data from Azure Data Explorer after accidental deletion?

Tags: backup, adx

I know that I cannot perform the backup of data in Azure Data Explorer. How can I restore the data if accidental deletion of data happens? If I want to restore the data from last week or day for example how can I do it?